# How to trim incomplete results from MySQL Select

Tags: mysql, trim

i have the next sub-query:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(
         (SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT PT.Factura  SEPARATOR '|') 
         FROM darwin.vt_partidas PT 
         WHERE PT.Pedimento = P.ID)
      ,1,30) AS 'Resultado' 
FROM darwin.vt_pedimentos P WHERE P.ID=130
```

I need to concat all results separated with | until i reach 130 characters, but my problem is that if at the end a result doesn't fit example:

i get the first 30 characters but the last result doesn't fit, i get:
result1|result2|result3|result

and i want this:
result1|result2|result3

(if the result doesn't fit, remove all characters from that result)

Thank you guys

Comment: The results aren't the same length

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: I need to insert the results in a maximum length of 190 characters and if this is not enough, insert the next 190 characters on the next field and so on

Comment: This sounds like a broken design :-(

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Updated your GROUP_CONCAT  and added another step to remove irrelevant data exceeding the 30 max length

```
SELECT
   @str:= left(GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT PT.Factura SEPARATOR '|'), 30) 
FROM
   vt_pedimentos P 
   INNER JOIN
      vt_partidas PT 
      ON PT.Pedimento = P.ID 
WHERE
   P.ID = 130;


 -- to check whether the last or truncated text exists in the table otherwise remove
select
   @str:= left(@str, 
   (
      length(@str) - length(reverse(left(reverse(@str), locate('|', reverse(@str)) - 1)))
   )
    - 1) 
FROM
   vt_pedimentos P 
where
   NOT EXISTS 
   (
      select
         1 
      from
         vt_partidas PT 
      where
         PT.Factura = reverse(left(reverse(@str), locate('|', reverse(@str)) - 1))
   )
   and P.ID = 130;
```

further enhancement - have it to one sql statement

Answer (score 0):

String manipulation is not a forte of SQL expressions.

But something like this should do it:

```
SELECT 
  IF(CHAR_LENGTH( GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT PT.Factura SEPARATOR '|') ) < 130
  , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT PT.Factura SEPARATOR '|')
  , SUBSTRING_INDEX( 
      SUBSTR( GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT PT.Factura SEPARATOR '|') ,1,130)
    , '|'
    , CHAR_LENGTH(        SUBSTR( GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT PT.Factura SEPARATOR '|') ,1,130)        )
     -CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(SUBSTR( GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT PT.Factura SEPARATOR '|') ,1,130),'|',''))
    )
  )
```

That's fairly complicated. It will be easier to decipher if we replace the `GROUP_CONCAT` expression with a placeholder. Let's have `res` represent `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT PT.Factura SEPARATOR '|')` expression.

```
SELECT
  IF(CHAR_LENGTH( res ) < 130
  , res
  , SUBSTRING_INDEX( 
      SUBSTR( res ,1,130)
    , '|'
    , CHAR_LENGTH(        SUBSTR( res ,1,130)        )
     -CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(SUBSTR( res ,1,130),'|',''))
    )
  )
```

Still ugly, but better. Let's break that down.

If the number of characters in `res` is less than 130, we're done. Just return res.

Otherwise, we need to trim res to 130 characters, we can use SUBSTRING function to do that.

Now, we want to trim the last `|` and the following characters. To do that, we can get a count of the number `|` separator characters. Then we know which one the last one is.

(We can get a count of the separator characters by replacing all separator characters with an empty string, then getting the length of that string, and subtracting that from the length of the original string. The  difference is the total length of the removed separator characters.

Then we can use that difference in a `SUBSTRING_INDEX` function to return all of the the characters before the last separator.

It's not a pretty solution. But it does implement an algorithm that satisfies the specification.